# How to create link in portlet to another page with liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay-6.2

I am using Liferay 6.2 and Tomcat 7.

First question, i have page like this `http://localhost:8080/group/page-two-portal/good` and i want to create a link that can access to that page. 
How to create link in portlet to that page ?

Second question, i want to know how to get baseurl in Liferay 6.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to create link in portlet to that page ?

Give friendly URL in `href` tag.

> i want to know how to get baseurl in Liferay 6.2 ?

```
List<Layout> navlist = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayouts(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), false);
for(Layout l : navlist){<%=l.getFriendlyURL()%>}
```

Thanks.